# multiple spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, autoload, spl

what is/are the benefit(s) of having multiple `spl_autoload_register`

example:

```
spl_autoload_register('autoload_systems');
spl_autoload_register('autoload_thirdparties');
spl_autoload_register('autoload_services');
```

vs:

using one

`spl_autoload_register('autoload');` or `__autoload();`

and then do the logic inside the function.

```
eg:
$ftp = new systems_ftp();
$services = new services_cron_email();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have one [`__autoload()`](http://php.net/__autoload) and you include a third party library which also had one, it would be clobbered.

Registering multiple autoloads with [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) ensures you can have your code dropped in with existing code (think libraries, etc) without clobbering or shadowing of existing/future autoloads.

In addition, the [PHP manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)...

> `spl_autoload_register()` provides a more flexible alternative for
>   autoloading classes. For this reason, using `__autoload()` is
>   discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

Comment: but having multiple spl_autoload_register is slower then just using one?

Comment: @GinoSullivan Perhaps, but I would hardly use that as an excuse to write code that uses `__autoload()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess no need to add multiple but it's on your logic.
The way spl_autoload_register works is awesome.
Suppose one have 3rd parties directories and that is usually manages through namespace which also represents their path.
Consider this simple class as autoloader class

```
 class MyAutoLoader {

     public function __construct()
     {
         spl_autoload_register( array($this, 'load') );
     }

     function load( $class )
     {
         $filepath = 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
         require_once( $filepath);
     }
 }
```

Then in index file include this loader file and create instance of this class:

```
$autoload = new MyAutoLoader();
```

Now you can directly create the instances of classes.
Suppose we have 'Person' class in directory `classes\QMS\SERVICES\Person.php` and same path is the namespace of that class

```
$person = new QMS\SERVICES\Person();
```

Now when when you will use new it will check if this class exists and value as a string will be passes to 'load' function of class 'MyAutoLoader'. and there it will get included. Or you can change the function 'load' to fix the path of your class files put your if conditions or whatever need to b done to fix the paths.